# How to maintain container widget width when we add a child column widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My code without `column` widget gives expected UI like this[image]

But when I add a `column` widget the width of the container is shrinking based on the `column` widget child like this

[image]

**Code:**

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Color(0xffE3E4EB),
  appBar: AppBar(
    titleTextStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
    backgroundColor: Color(0xffE3E4EB),
    elevation: 0,
    actions: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
        child: Container(
          width: 60,
          height: 60,
          child: Icon(Icons.done),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 120, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 40),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
        // child: Column( // disable this 3 line to check the UI 
        //   children: [Text("Dinesh Nagarajan")],
        // ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

How I can maintain the width of my container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the width property of container to `double.infinity`. It will expand to fit the maximum available width.